# Too many AJAX calls

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

My code is so messy. I create 1 Ajax call everytime I display an element. My table will have a fixed number of 80 rows. How can I simplify my repetitive AJAX calls.

HTML

```
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="form-group row mb-0" >
        <div class="col-12">
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm mySelect2 " name="111" id="111">
                <?php
                include ('server_side/connection.php');
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_subjects";
                $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['subject_code'];?>"><?php echo $row['subject_code'];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
<td><span id="description_111"></span></td>
<td><span id="prerequisite_111"></span></td>
<td><span id="unit_111"></span></td>
```

AJAX

```
$("#111").change(function(){
        var subject_code = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server_side/load_subjectdesc.php",
            data: {subject_code: subject_code},
            success: function(result){
            $("#description_111").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
    $("#111").change(function(){
        var subject_code = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server_side/load_subjectpreq.php",
            data: {subject_code: subject_code},
            success: function(result){
            $("#prerequisite_111").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
    $("#111").change(function(){
        var subject_code = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server_side/load_subjectunit.php",
            data: {subject_code: subject_code},
            success: function(result){
            $("#unit_111").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

One Ajax per One item to be displayed is too much. How can I simplify or remove so many AJAX calls?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can't you have your PHP load the whole lot into a JSON structure, pick that up via one Ajax call, and then populate your table from it in Javascript?

Comment: He's right, do all in one, with a response such as `{description: descriptionData, prerequisite: prerequisiteData, unit: unitData}`, each xxData being the data sent back by each of your current api calls

Comment: But how would I append to corresponding span if I use {description: descriptionData, prerequisite: prerequisiteData, unit: unitData}?

Comment: @MandyShaw I am not familiar with JSON, can u perhaps drop some snippet for me to look?

Comment: I could, but you would do much better to learn it from a proper tutorial or textbook. You really will need to know it sooner rather than later. The Wikipedia article is a start, but the really key fact is that JSON is native to Javascript (hence the name), so a piece of cake to work with once you've got it there.

Comment: The thing is, I am not just populating a table. The content of a row depends on what select value is active. THe 1st column of table is a select, the second and third column are info about the 1st column. When value of 1st column is changed, the 2nd and 3rd values changes too.

Comment: `$("#description_111").html(result.description);` and so on

Comment: I think I am not clear on what I am saying, here is the repo https://github.com/jjjhanreyyy/Pyo-App , Please navigate to the curriculum page. The database is included as pyo.sql

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a php page which will return a JSON of this form:

```
{
    description: 'descriptionvalue',
    perequisite: 'perequisitevalue',
    unit: 'unitvalue'
}
```

and you would send an AJAX request to it, like:

```
$("#111").change(function(){
    var subject_code = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "server_side/yourpage.php",
        data: {subject_code: subject_code},
        success: function(result){
            for (var key in result) $("#" + key + "_111").html(result[key]);
        }
    });
});
```

You could refine this further:

```
function myChange(idVal) {
    $("#" + idVal).change(function(){
        var subject_code = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "server_side/yourpage.php",
            data: {subject_code: subject_code},
            success: function(result){
                for (var key in result) $("#" + key + "_" + idVal).html(result[key]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```